# length of audio file for playeffect in SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, simpleaudioengine

for play effect using `[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"sound.mp3"];`

What is the limit length of used audio file?

Answer (score 0):

I think u can refer AVAudioFoundation for this use AvAudioPlayer and its property "duration" work for it.

use .h

```
    < AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol>
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

.m

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataAudio error:nil];

audioPlayer.delegate = self;

 float sliderLength = [audioPlayer duration];
```